# NodeJS streams - a leaky pipe?

Tags: node.js, stream, pipe, memory-leaks

I'm doing a lot of work with NodeJS streams at the moment.

One thing I find myself needing is a 'leaky pipe'.

Like `stream.PassThrough`, but which just drops data if (and only if) it has no where to send it.

Does such a thing already exist?

Is there a way of finding out (within a `stream.Transform`) how many downstream pipes are connected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually came up with a solution:

```
LeakyTransform.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, done) {
  if (this._readableState.pipesCount > 0) {
    this.push(chunk);
  }
  done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PassThrough implements _transfrom as following:

```
PassThrough.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
  cb(null, chunk);
};
```

I think what you need can be implemented like this:

```
Leak.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, cb) {
};
```

i.e. no-op

Comment: Thanks, but when the 'leaky pipe' is piped into something, it should no longer leak.  I'm not looking for a `/dev/null`.